# Flash Professional IDE Deletes All ActionScript. What Now?

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

### Question

When the Flash Professional IDE crashes, how do you view error information to decipher what went wrong with the application itself? (i.e., how do you view the errors that stem from bugs in Flash, itself, as opposed to code)?

---

### Background

Often, when the Flash Professional IDE has an internal bug/error during publishing, it provides no information about it. Instead, it just deletes all the actionscript from the file, resulting in a movie that just flickers because all frames are set to play. That's an insane way to deal with errors!!

Typically what happens is it successfully creates a SWF file that contains only graphics and no code. At the same time, it always fails to create the SWC file, which is the only thing I need. Since the resulting SWF file contains no ActionScript of any kind, including class links, it's completely useless.

I'm lost as to what to do about this.  I publish certain files and everything just flickers (because there are no `stop()` calls anymore).

At times, the error can be as simple as a typo in code.  Often, the error is some other obscure internal bug in Flash Professional.  Sometimes, I convert the same file to CS4 and everything works without modification! In other cases, I don't have that luxury.  In CS5, I see this behavior significantly more often than I did in CS4 and it's starting to drive me up the wall.

Also, note the output and compiler error windows have no information. The only way I know something is wrong is 1) the SWC is missing 2) experience from having seen this kind awful error handling for years.

---

### Summary

At times, I can't publish from the IDE because of bugs in Flash Professional (i.e., not code). Often, when those errors occur, there is no information about it; the only symptom is a flickering movie (Because all actionscript is deleted).

> What can I do to get some kind of insight into why the IDE is "crashing?"

I wouldn't mind the crashing so much if Adobe AT LEAST gave some error logs or ***something*** to work with so I can address the problems.  This is driving me crazy.

Note: I run OS X 10.6.6, Flash CS5 v11.0.2.489 with the latest debug version of the flash player. However, this behavior occurs in all versions of Flash on all platforms.

Comment: http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page :D

Comment: @divillysausages: will FlashDevelop IDE allow me to visually create graphics/animations? That's all I use Flash Pro for: all my code is in Flash Builder (Flex).

Comment: If you're talking vector graphics, then no. Bitmap graphics (jpgs, pngs, gifs etc), can be embedded or loaded at runtime. Like other suggestions, externalise your code - use Flash just to create graphics if needed. Also, check out TortoiseSVN - http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ - to create a local SVN. You can commit your work regularly, then if something goes wrong, you can just revert and not lose all your work. It save having about 100 versions of your file as well

Comment: @divillysausages: Generally speaking, your suggestions are great ones but 1) all of our code resides in a Flex Project managed in Flash Builder and stored in a subversion repository 2) Flash Pro is used exclusively for vector graphics and animation 3) our issues stem entirely from *internal flash bugs* during the publishing of SWC files. So, basically, I agree on all the points you made but what I seek is a method to debug Flash, itself or at least view some error logs because, currently, there's no indication of what's going wrong, aside from all code being deleted and the SWC not publishing

Answer (score 0):

I would externalize your actionscript, and run your debugging that way.  Without seeing your code it's a little hard to understand how/why this is happening, however, you can setup interval traces and checks to see if and what is getting loaded.

But typically when something like that is the outcome of your code, it leads me to believe your installation is corrupt (or perhaps the player is, or something in your OS).

Happy to help, if you want further details/explanation.

Also, if you're flash IDE is crashing, check out this link:  http://forums.adobe.com/message/2397055#2397055

I'm not sure what version of OSX you're running, versus flash player, etc... But that might help.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond @TNC.  I wish it were a code issue.  Then I'd fix it. :). Unfortunately, it's flash bugs that cause these problems. In fact, the only code in my files are calls to `stop()` in a couple places on the timeline. So I need to try and find the logs for the application, or something that can help me discern why it's failing. This happens semi-often, more so in CS5 than ever in CS4, and I've finally gotten sick of it. I run OS X 10.6.6, Flash CS5 v11.0.2.489 with the latest debug version of the flash player.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have experienced similar problems, especially with larger files (when it's really not only a nuisance you've just lost everything you've been working on).  I have also had broken FLA files rendered completely unusable after the IDE crashed.
That led me to the same conclusion I have come to for every version of Flash since Flash 4: The Adobe IDE is a pain in the lower intestine, and if you're not doing a lot of keyframe animations, it's not worth paying a single cent for.

If you work with ActionScript a lot, you should seriously consider switching to another IDE and compiler: They all are more suited for programming, they all are significantly faster, they all are more reliable, and they all support good versioning plugins(!).

I have three suggestions:

1. [FDT](http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/)

   An eclipse based solution with great professional features, such as refactoring, templates, code formatting and profiling.  I have been using it for years, and I absolutely love it.
2. [Adobe Flash Builder](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/flashbuilder/using/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4ce276-8000.html)

   Adobe's professional IDE, also eclipse based.  It lacks some of the more elaborate features that FDT has, but it's okay, and it is a bit cheaper than the FDT Max.
3. [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page)

   In my experience not quite as powerful as the other two, but free, open source and still infinitely better than the Flash IDE.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond. I wish this were just an issue with code. Then my problems would be simple. Unfortunately, the issue is with Flash, itself. All my code is in Flash Builder. I use Flash Pro for timeline-based animations and custom Flex graphics. I'm finding CS5 is incredibly buggy compared to CS4. I can't take it anymore (but I have not choice) so I need to figure out how to get information when Flash, itself, crashes...

Comment: @gmale: I feel with you, really.  Damn graphics people, you never get rid of them ;)  But as for information: There is always the crash log, but that won't help you one bit ( it might help Adobe fixing the bug, though ).   I have sometimes been able to fix problems by converting files from CS4 format to CS5 and vice versa, but in others there was just no way to fix them.  I have come to keeping locked SVN copies at all times, and saving very frequently when working in Flash.

Comment: yeah, I save alternate versions like a maniac with flash. You have to! We used to use `Version Cue` but what a terrible piece of software that was! Do you know where "the crash log" is? Or how to access it? The fact that one exists, gives me hope. Maybe I'll start googling *that*...

Comment: The Mac OS X crash reporter usually saves the logs into ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter.  But even if there is one - this will only display the Max OS X stack trace.  I doubt it will help much, sorry.